# MimeType to encoded files

Tags: java, jsf-2, web

i need to return a encoded PDF, but i need the MIME type to do it. What i should use it?

Thank's!

```
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

    ec.responseReset(); 
     ec.setResponseContentType("??")
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + this.fileName + ".pdf" + "\""); 

    OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
    output.write(encrypted);
    output.flush();
    output.close();

    fc.responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what an encoded PDF is and how it differs from a regular one. Since you export it as a `.pdf` file though, I'd have thought the standard PDF mime type of `application/pdf` would apply.

Comment: Well, worked, but an encoded that i mean, is actually encrypted.

Comment: As far as I know, encrypted PDFs are still perfectly valid PDF documents, and are processed by exactly the same software. There's no reason I can think of not to use the standard `application/pdf` mime type.